# Mailchimp API / URL Construction

Tags: url, download, mailchimp

I’m trying to pull data in from Mailchimp and have most of it done. However, I’m trying to pull ALL SURVEY data with answers.. and I’m not sure how to proceed with the URL assignment in Alteryx for download ..

How to handle the `{id=Id}` and pull everything?

I’m expecting to show all survey responses from every question.

Comment: How do I construct a url.  HTTPS://us31.Mailchimp.com//reporting/surveys/{outreach_id}/question….  What do I do with the “{outreach_id}”… I want to pull all data not just 1 ID

Comment: You would be more likely to get an answer to this if you asked Mailchimp directly.  Unless Mailchimp has publicly documented this, nobody here will be able to answer it.

Comment: I have the documentation but I am uncertain how to design the web address  ..   the below is the api root address… but where is shows {outreach_id}, it errors out……………… reporting/surveys/{outreach_id}/responses